# How to use a conditional ORDER BY in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, order-by, condition

I have the table courses where we have some fields and also the field `course(string)`, `favorited(bool)`, `favoritedDate(dateTime)`, dateUpload.

The teacher uploads the course and this date is stored in the `dateUpload` field. If the teacher flag this course as favorite this information is a number 1 in the field `favorited` and the date it was flagged is stored in the field `favoritedDate`.

Now I need to retrieve all courses from a specific teacher and then order the list by date: If the course is flagged `favorited=1` should ordered by `favoritedDate,dateUpload desc`, if `favorited=0` should be ordered only by  `dateUpload desc`.

This is what I have so far but it is not working:

```
SELECT * from courses where teacherId = 23 
ORDER BY 
  CASE favorited WHEN 1 THEN favoritedDate, dateUpload
    else dateUpload
  END
  DESC
;
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A case expression returns an atomic value so you can't return:

```
favoritedDate, dateUpload
```

I think this will do what you want:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE favorited WHEN 1 THEN favoritedDate 
                          ELSE dateUpload 
    END DESC, dateUpload
```

Answer (score 6):

As Lennart explains, a `CASE` expression in MySQL can only produce a single value, not two or more. I think this would suite your problem:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN favorited = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    CASE WHEN favorited = 1 THEN favoritedDate END,
    dateUpload DESC ;
```

If the `favoritedDate` values are `NULL` when the item is not "favourited", then you really don't need the `favorited` column at all. The information is stored in `favoritedDate`: If it's null, it's not a favourite. If it's not null, it is. The `ORDER BY` in that case (not much simpler, due to MySQL sorting nulls before not null values):

```
ORDER BY
    (favoritedDate IS NULL),
    favoritedDate,
    dateUpload DESC ;
```